# leaflet-rails gem -- "undefined method map"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet

I'm trying to implement [leaflet-rails](https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails) that offers a Google-like geocoder.

I receive this error message from the third line below:

```
undefined method `map' for
#<#<Class:0x007ff7052f47a8>:0x007ff6dca48758> Did you mean?  tap
```

Which is:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="mapid" style = "height: 400px; width: 200px; "></div>
    <%= map(:center => {
    :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
    :zoom => 18
      }) %>   
</div>
```

I wrote this code like they recommended:

**config/initializers/leaflet.rb:**

```
Leaflet.tile_layer = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
Leaflet.attribution = '?'
Leaflet.max_zoom = 18
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<div id="mapid" style = "height: 400px; width: 200px; "></div>
<%= map(:center => {
:latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
:zoom => 18
 }) %>
```

**application.scss.**

```
/*
*= require flexslider.css
*= require blueimp-gallery
*= require blueimp-gallery-indicator
*= require blueimp-gallery-video
*= require leaflet
*/

// Graphical variables
@import "config/variables";
@import "config/bootstrap_variables";

// External libraries
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";

// Your CSS
@import "layout/index";
@import "components/index";
@import "pages/index";
@import "vendor/index";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require underscore
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary
//= require attachinary
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require blueimp-gallery
//= require blueimp-gallery-fullscreen
//= require blueimp-gallery-indicator
//= require blueimp-gallery-video
//= require jquery.blueimp-gallery
//= require leaflet
//= require_tree .
```

I ran `bundle install`.

Where should `map` be called?

Comment: Try `gem 'leaflet-rails', require: "leaflet-rails/view_helpers"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and to me it didn't work. I substituted this line on gemfile and ran bundle after and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post your application.css and .js?

Comment: Yes, sure! I updated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use these methods from the leaflet rails gem and I installed it manually instead and worked for me after some adjusts on javascript code.